# SQL Server client String to (forced) integer conversion issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, type-conversion

Okay I'm using VB.net and added a SQL Server connection (`.mdf` file), and a table. I have CHANGED the input type from int to varchar (and others) to deal with split postal codes (ie "101 00", instead of "339022").

Anyways, now my table will not accept a string variable in the insert query because it's telling me the SQL Server table wants an integer. I've updated that information and refreshed it. Not quite sure what I need to change or do for this to click. I've tried different variables, closing, reopening etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried rebuilding my query with no luck. This is the error I'm getting after turning option strict on. This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

```
System.Number.StringToNumber(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, ref System.Number.NumberBuffer, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo, bool)  
System.Number.ParseInt32(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)   
string.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider)  
System.Data.Common.Int32Storage.Set(int, object)   
System.Data.DataColumn.this[int].set(int, object)
```

Comment: Please include the code which is doing the insert.

Comment: This has nothing specifically to do with SQL Server. The database will accept text without issue. Based on the information you have provided, it appears to be an implicit conversion that is taking place somewhere. In that case, if you turn `Option Strict On` in your project properties, the issue will be flagged by the compiler and not sneak through to run time. You should pretty much ALWAYS have `Option Strict On`, so turn it `On` in the IDE options as well, so it will be `On` by default in all future projects. You're likely to get many other potential issues flagged as well.

Comment: i tried rebuilding my query with no luck. this is the error im getting after turning strict on  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
 System.Number.StringToNumber(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, ref System.Number.NumberBuffer, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo, bool)
 System.Number.ParseInt32(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)
 string.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider)
 System.Data.Common.Int32Storage.Set(int, object)
 System.Data.DataColumn.this[int].set(int, object)

Comment: Just as Tim said, we need to see the sql insert code that is causing the error.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need luck. It looks like your `DataTable` is expecting an `Integer` so it's the `DataTable` schema you need to fix. How did you create that `DataTable`?

Comment: Secondly, don't post information in comments that you should have posted in the question in the first place. No one should have to read comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a database, and it has a table with some number column:

```
TblAddress
--------
Street Varchar
PostalCode int
```

And you wrote (or visual studio wrote) some code to put data into the column. Now it's not exactly clear what method you're using to access this database but it doesn't matter- the concept will remain the same. I'm going to guess that it's either straight insert queries, ie you wrote something like this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblAddress VALUES(@street, @postalcode", "some connection string here")
cmd.Parameters.Add("@street", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = "Microsoft way"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@postalcode", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = 339022
```

And so on. Or maybe you're using a DataSet (you have a file called Something.XSD in your solution explorer) and when you double click it you see something that looks like a db. It is important to remember that a DataSet is a client side container that has datatables for storing data and tableadapters for pushing data between the dataset and true db - it can be created with reference to the db bit it is not the db and it can diverge - a datatable can have more or fewer columns than the table in the db to which it relates etc. So your  will have been set up as an int column

Or maybe you're using entity framework, which like the dataset is a suite of client side code that can be modelled on the db but it can diverge

---

The crucial point here is that if you originally had an int column on db table and you created client side code targeting an int, if you change the db type later there is nothing that automagicallly updates the client side code. If you're using an insert directly you have to go and change the SqlDbType of the parameter. If you're using a DataSet you have to open the dataset, find the column and update its type. If you're using EF you find your client side class entity and update the type of the property

TLDR: even if you change the db type there is still another change you need to make in your code

---

A major thing potentially tripping you up here is vb.net option strict being off. VB language variants default settings have long been targeted towards hobbyist programmers who don't necessarily know or care the difference between a number and a string that contains numerical characters. It allows things like:

```
Dim i as Integer = "123"
```

"123" is a String, not an Integer, there is a conversion possibility but only if the string doesn't have any crap in it. By default if you do something like this VB will do the conversion for you implicitly and this isn't really a great idea. By not forcing the developer to think about the conversion at design time it means they also haven't thought about errors that will happen during the conversion nor written in any handling for them.

Click your project properties and in the compiler options turn On every option that has an On. You might well see tens of errors suddenly appear but that answer to that is not to turn the option off again, but to properly fix the error

It won't catch everything, for example a DbParameter `.Value` is an Object, which will still accept your postalcode string with a space in, and fail internally if you declared the parameter type as some numeric, but being mindful of your datatypes at all times and not treating them as synonymous will resolve a lot of headaches

Comment: Thanks for simplifying that for me. That's pretty much what had to be done, I ended up deleting the Adapter and the DataSet, went through the designer and removed a rats nest of code, then rebinding the datagrid and redoing my sql commands.  it... was something.

Comment: Next time, just right click the tabkeadapter (not the datatable) header and choose Configure, then press finish - it should be all that's needed. you can also trip through the column in the datatable and the Parameters collection of every command in the table adapter, but often reconfiguring is simpler. If you have multiple queries in your tableadapter doing it in the xml (close the dataset, right click in solution explorer, open with, xml editor) can be a quick way too