# How to pass parameterized variable to avoid sql injection for VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, prepared-statement

I want to pass OrderBy and OrderAs variable as parameter in below select query to avoid sql injection. Please help me to solve this.

Below is the original code:

```
Dim strSearchSQL As String

        strSearchSQL = "   SELECT ALNC_CD, TERRITORY_CD, BRIO_DISPLAY_NAME, RPT_SEQ_NUM, CARR_CD, "
        strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & "   COMP_ABBRV, ALNC_NAME, TO_CHAR(EFF_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EFF_DT, "
        strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & "   TO_CHAR(DISC_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS DISC_DT"
        strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & "   FROM ALNC_TB"

        If Not OrderBy = "" And Not OrderAs = "" Then
            strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & " ORDER BY " & OrderBy & " " & OrderAs
        Else
            strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & "  ORDER BY ALNC_NAME"
        End If

        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
        cmd.CommandText = strSearchSQL
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = Connection.GetConnection
```

I modified it to below way to pass these two variable as parameter but I am getting error "ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name". Please help me to identify where am I doing mistake?

Below is the modified code :

```
Dim strSearchSQL As String
        'Below section added by Sid
        Dim Order As String
        Order = OrderBy & " " & OrderAs
        'End

        strSearchSQL = "   SELECT ALNC_CD, TERRITORY_CD, BRIO_DISPLAY_NAME, RPT_SEQ_NUM, CARR_CD, "
        strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & "   COMP_ABBRV, ALNC_NAME, TO_CHAR(EFF_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EFF_DT, "
        strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & "   TO_CHAR(DISC_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS DISC_DT"
        strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & "   FROM ALNC_TB"

        If Not OrderBy = "" And Not OrderAs = "" Then
            'strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & " ORDER BY " & OrderBy & " " & OrderAs
            ''Above line is commeneted out and Below line added by Sid
            strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & " ORDER BY :Order "
        Else
            strSearchSQL = strSearchSQL & "  ORDER BY ALNC_NAME"
        End If

        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
        cmd.CommandText = strSearchSQL
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = Connection.GetConnection
        'Below code added by Sid
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        If Not OrderBy = "" And Not OrderAs = "" Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Order", OracleType.VarChar).Value = Order
        End If
        'End
```

Comment: try this out
[SQL Server client String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61135133/4583310)

Comment: I don't think you can pass column names as params like this. Params usually only cover values. Possibly you'll need to manually build your order string with case statements etc. However, this one looks interesting... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043672/how-to-generate-dynamic-order-by-clause-in-pl-sql-procedure